# Access untranslated content of Django's ugettext_lazy

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm looking for a sane way to get to the untranslated content of a `ugettext_lazy`ied string. I found two ways, but I'm not happy with either one:

```
the_string = ugettext_lazy('the content')
the_content = the_string._proxy____args[0] # ewww!
```

or

```
from django.utils.translation import activate, get_language
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode

the_string = ugettext_lazy('the content')
current_lang = get_language()
activate('en')
the_content = force_unicode(the_string)
activate(current_lang)
```

The first piece of code accesses an attribute that has been explicitly marked as private, so there is no telling how long this code will work. The second solution is overly verbose and slow.

Of course, in the actual code, the definition of the `ugettext_lazy`ied string and the code that accesses it are miles appart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another two options. Not very elegant, but not private api and is not slow.

- Number one, define your own ugettext_lazy:

  ```
  from django.utils import translation

  def ugettext_lazy(str):
      t = translation.ugettext_lazy(str)
      t.message = str
      return t

  >>> text = ugettext_lazy('Yes')
  >>> text.message
  "Yes"
  >>> activate('lt')
  >>> unicode(text)
  u"Taip"
  >>> activate('en')
  >>>> unicode(text)
  u"Yes"
  ```
- Number two: redesign your code. Define untranslated messages separately from where you use them:

  ```
  gettext = lambda s: s
  some_text = gettext('Some text')

  lazy_translated = ugettext_lazy(text)
  untranslated = some_text
  ```

Answer (score 7):

This is the better version of your second solution

```
from django.utils import translation

the_string = ugettext_lazy('the content')
with translation.override('en'):
    content = unicode(the_string)
```

Comment: It is the best one when langauage translation is active(french) and we want `en` text from translated text. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that (but you shouldn't):

```
the_string = ugettext_lazy('the content')
the_string._proxy____args[0]
```